# RxJS and Angular HttpClient: use of forkJoin for multiple sequential requests

Tags: typescript, rxjs, concatenation, angular-httpclient, fork-join

In RxJS (ES6) I'm trying to get the result in a sequentially series of operations in a single Observable.

I'm not sure If I have to use a forkJoin (but I would like the operations to be executed sequentially) or a concat operator (but I would like to just be notified at the end when all of them are executed).

I TRIED:

**forkJoin**

```
  sync(): Observable<any> {
    return from(this.db.getProducts()).pipe(
        map(products => {
            if ( !products ) {
                return of(true);
            }

            const batch: Observable<any>[] = [];
            for ( const product of products ) {
              if ( product.toBeSync ) {
                  batch.push(this.api.updateProduct(product));
              }
            }

            return forkJoin(batch);
        })
    );
  }
```

**concat**

```
  sync(): Observable<any> {
    return from(this.db.getProducts()).pipe(
        map(products => {
            if ( !products ) {
                return of(true);
            }

            const batch: Observable<any>[] = [];
            for ( const product of products ) {
              if ( product.toBeSync ) {
                  batch.push(this.api.updateProduct(product));
              }
            }

            return concat(batch);
        })
    );
  }
```

In both cases I can't ever see the observables coming from the `HttpClient` doing their job (no http request sent), but I can see the logging.

The called method in the batch it's the following:

```
  updateProduct(product: Product) {
      console.log('calling...');
      const options = this.getDefaultRequestOptions();
      return this.http.post('update_product', product, options);
  }
```

I call the sync() function like the following:

```
this.productService.sync().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('sync done');
}, error => this.utils.handleError(error));
```

**Output:**

```
(8) calling...
sync done
```

but no HTTP request starting.

If I do the same outside the forkJoin/concat in the pipe map I can see the HTTP request sent.

```
sync(): Observable<any> {

    const product = new Product(null, 'Title', 'Desc.', 'CODE');
    return this.api.updateProduct(product);

}
```

What am I missing?

**--- UPDATE - SOLUTION ---**

```
sync(): Observable<any> {
    return from(this.db.getProducts()).pipe(
        flatMap(products => {

            if ( !products ) {
                return of(true);
            }

            const batch: Observable<any>[] = [];
            for ( const product of products ) {
              if ( product.toBeSync ) {
                  batch.push(this.api.updateProduct(product));
              }
            }

            console.log(batch);

            return concat(...batch);
            // return forkJoin(batch);
        })
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
sync(): Observable<any> {
  return from(this.db.getProducts()).pipe(
    map(products => {
      const batch: Observable<any>[] = [];
      for (const product of products) {
        batch.push(this.api.updateProduct(product));
      }
     return batch;
   }),
   switchMap(batch => forkJoin(batch)),
  )
}
```

This is assuming `this.db.getProducts()` is synchronous static data and not an observable/asynchronous data.

Then you can try doing

```
  this.productService.sync().subscribe(() => { console.log('sync done'); });
```

And see if any API calls are being made.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not `forkJoin/concat` here, it is using `map` to return another observable.

In your code, `map` would return `Observable<Observable<any>>`. Your IDE should highlight this stuff(don't use `any`, maybe it is a problem here).

Your solution would be to change `map` to `concatMap`(at least for test) and next *chain* should work.

Also, debug `subscribe` and its return value to see what you have.

Comment: Your sight it's right and fundamental to aim to correct resolution but the solution needs a bit more thoughts on. Thank you btw.

Comment: “What am I missing?” was the question. “Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, and you feed him for a lifetime” - my answer. And for a full solution - please, provide stackblitz for reproduction(to save time). P.S. don’t forget to unsubscribe(prefer take(1)/first/takeUntil/AsyncPipe). Good luck ;)

Comment: Thank you a lot @andriishupta as in fact you're answer pointed out to the right spot to correct, also a deep study of the single operator was needed. I believe in this cases referring up to a doc it's essential. Also your last suggestion about unsubscriptions pros and patterns worths some consideration: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0